# Port-Forwarding and Routing on Windows Server 2019

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding, windows-server-2019, ip-routing

we run several virtualized servers (all Windows Server 2019) in a cloud environment.
There is one server used as router (with a public IP and a privte IP 192.168.100.10)
and two further servers have an IIS running.

The port-forwarding on the router is configured as follows:

```
Adresse         Anschluss   Adresse         Anschluss
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
0.0.0.0         443         192.168.100.1   443
0.0.0.0         4443        192.168.100.2   4443
```

It works fine. Incoming HTTP requests from extern (via public IP address of the router) on port 443 are routed to server with IP 192.168.100.1 and in the same way requests on port 4443.

For the web applications on both webservers there is a special requirement: Some custumers want to restrict client access to specific IP addresses (e.g. 37.38.39.40).

This does not work because the webservers see the private IP address of the router (192.168.100.10) instead of the clients IP address.

On a redundant inhouse network this concept works. The only differece is the router. It is a Netgear router instead of a Windows Server 2019.

Question: Is it possible to configure a Windows Server 2019 in a way that port-forwarding / routings works in a way that the destination servers see the original IP adress of requesting clients instead of private router IP address?

Thanks!